# Request method 'POST' is not supported, whitescreen error

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

Why i get 405 error white screen while using POST?
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]
Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 405

My controller

```
@Controller
public class CurrencyController {

    private final CurrencyService currencyService;

    public CurrencyController(CurrencyService currencyService) {
        this.currencyService = currencyService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to the Currency Rate Calculator!");
        return "index.html";
    }

    @PostMapping("/1")
    public String convertCurrency(
            @RequestParam String baseCurrency,
            @RequestParam String targetCurrency,
            @RequestParam double amount,
            Model model) {

        String rate = currencyService.getExchangeRate(baseCurrency, targetCurrency);


        double result = amount * Double.valueOf(rate);

        model.addAttribute("baseCurrency", "USD");
        model.addAttribute("targetCurrency", "EUR");
        model.addAttribute("amount", 100.0);
        model.addAttribute("result", 85.0);

        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

index.html is in category resources/static

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Currency Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/1" method="post">
  <label for="baseCurrency">Base Currency:</label>
  <select id="baseCurrency" name="baseCurrency" required>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  </select>

  <label for="targetCurrency">Target Currency:</label>
  <select id="targetCurrency" name="targetCurrency" required>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  </select>

  <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
  <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" required>

  <button type="submit">Convert</button>

  <h1>Conversion Result</h1>

  <p>Result: <span th:text="${result}"></span></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
server.port=8000
```

I tried to move files in different categories, but the only request is worked is GET. If request is GET it do not paste the result in HTML (85.0 in this case) .

Comment: Change the annotation `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Controller `CurrencyController` should be annotated with `@RequestMapping`